# Read Cortex A15 Performance Counter from User Space

Tags: arm, kernel-module, performancecounter, cortex-a

I am trying to read the performance counters (cycle and event count registers) of my ARM big.LITTLE. It consists of 4 Cortex A7 and 4 Cortex A 15 Cores. I have no problems reading the values of the performance counters  if I set my tested task on the A7 core but if I want to test the same task on Cortex A15 I get an "illegal instruction". I put the code for enabling the counters below. 
I think its because my kernelmodule only enables the performance counter of the A7 to userspace. But I can't figure out how to enable the counters of the A15 to userspace. 
Does someone have an idea how I could do it?
I appreciate any help.

`#define PERF_DEF_OPTS (1 | 16)`

`#define DRVR_NAME "enable_arm_pmu"`

```
static void enable_cpu_counter(void* data){

        /*Enable counters to user land*/
        __asm__("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(1));
        __asm__("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" :: "r"(PERF_DEF_OPTS));
        __asm__ ("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 1" :: "r"(0x8000000f));
}

static void disable_cpu_counter(void* data){

        __asm__("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(0));
        __asm__("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" :: "r"(PERF_DEF_OPTS));
        __asm__ ("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 1" :: "r"(0x8000000f));

}


static int hello_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Performance counter enable\n");
        on_each_cpu(enable_cpu_counter, NULL, 1);
        printk(KERN_INFO "[" DRVR_NAME "] initialised");
        return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Performance counter disabled\n");
        on_each_cpu(disable_cpu_counter, NULL, 1);
        printk(KERN_INFO "[" DRVR_NAME "] unloaded");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
`
```

Comment: Assuming this is Linux, just make sure your kernel is built with `CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS`, and use the existing perf subsystem - trying to reinvent it from scratch isn't a good use of time.

Comment: It is linux 3.10 but I can't just use the perf subsystem, since its a project for university. The project is almost finished, the only point missing are the measurements for the A15 cores and I don't see what I am missing. I looked up the registers in the according ARM technical reference manuals but they are the same so it should work fine if they are enabled from userspace.

Comment: Is your system running HMP (all 8 cores at once) or the old cluster switching scheme (where the bL switcher only presents 4 'virtual' cores to Linux)? If it's the latter, then you're going to have to deal with all the horrible context switching of PMU registers, event rescheduling, etc. across switches.